# Чтение чисел из файла с++

Tags: c++

Есть файл в нем числа.Вывести все числа удалив из них повторяющиеся цифры.
к примеру было 112 а должно получиться 12. помогите с чего лучше начать плез

Comment: Покажите что уже сделано

Comment: Начните с чтения чисел из файла. С этим есть проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Такие вопросы здесь обычно не решают (Это не школа/универ).

Почитайте про чтение цифр и файлов (Это самое сложное). Обязательно посмотри формат хранения цифр (бинарный или строковый).

Алгоритм поиска одинаковых цифр можно сделать превеликое множество. Можно использовать контейнер "set" для удаления повторяющихся цифр.

Основной помощник: http://ru.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: Это против правил форума, но нельзя не заплюсовать такой ответ :)

Comment: Почему бы не помочь человеку? :)